# Convert Excel file to CSV - cannot supress Excel prompt window

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, vbscript, gulp

I have a Gulp task watches Excel file and runs VBScript:

Gulp code:

```javascript
.pipe(shell([
    'XlsToCsv.vbs test test.xlsx test.csv'
]))
```

VBScript code:

```vb
If WScript.Arguments.Count < 3 Then
    WScript.Echo "Please specify the sheet, the source, the destination files. Usage: ExcelToCsv <sheetName> <xls/xlsx source file> <csv destination file>"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

csv_format = 6

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

src_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Wscript.Arguments.Item(1))
dest_file = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(WScript.Arguments.Item(2))

Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)

oBook.Sheets(WScript.Arguments.Item(0)).Select
oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format

oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

It works fine except the prompt jumps when I resave the file in CSV format.
Like "File with this name already exists. Do you want to save it?"

I can't delete the previous file before saving because the Gulp watcher will trigger code execution.
`oBook.Close SaveChanges = True` and `oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False` didn't work.

I need to run this script silently on every saving.

What command should I add to the script?

P.S. I don't mind to use any other script, except PowerShell - `Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned` causes error

> Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE...\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied

Comment: Re: PowerShell - You need to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy` from an elevated prompt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either delete an existing file before saving

```vb
If objFSO.FileExists(dest_file) Then objFSO.DeleteFile dest_file
oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format
```

or set `DisplayAlerts = False` to suppress prompts (which also enforces replacing existing files):

```vb
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format
```

Comment: 1. I can't delete the file because the Gulp watcher triggers unnecessary code execution
2. I've added the DisplayAlerts = False in wrong place.
Thanks!